# Question about quicksort with std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, quicksort

Below are some code I found from internet which is using integer array for input. It is working well but if I change array to vector, it just print the original input 95, 45, 48, 98, 1, 485, 65, 478, 1, 2325. Can anyone explain the reason of it happens and how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;



            void printArray(vector<int> array, int n)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                    cout << array[i] << endl;
            }

            void quickSort(vector<int> array, int low, int high)
            {
                int i = low;
                int j = high;
                int pivot = array[(i + j) / 2];
                int temp;

                while (i <= j)
                {
                    while (array[i] < pivot)
                        i++;
                    while (array[j] > pivot)
                        j--;
                    if (i <= j)
                    {
                        temp = array[i];
                        array[i] = array[j];
                        array[j] = temp;
                        i++;
                        j--;
                    }
                }
                if (j > low)
                    quickSort(array, low, j);
                if (i < high)
                    quickSort(array, i, high);
            }

            int main()
            {
                vector<int> array = {95, 45, 48, 98, 1, 485, 65, 478, 1, 2325};
                int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

                cout << "Before Quick Sort :" << endl;
                printArray(array, n);

                quickSort(array, 0, n);

                cout << "After Quick Sort :" << endl;
                printArray(array, n);
                return (0);
            }
```

Comment: As I understand you've posted well working code. It would be better if you posted the broken piece of code.

Comment: Why bother? Just use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort). In 98+% of cases it's going to be better than what *you* can write or *good enough*. You need a very special situation to justify writing your own sort (IMHO).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have changed it.

Comment: You pass the `vector` by value so a copy is created and the function sort that copy. It doesn't effect the original `vector` in `main()`.

Comment: @TszYeeHa `int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);` -- This is not how you get the number of entries in a `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` has  a `size()` function.  Thus the `n` you're using in the code has more than likely an incorrect value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the vector by value to the `quicksort` function, which causes it to operate on a copy of the input vector (hence the original vector remains unchanged). A possible solution is to pass it by reference. So the declaration of `quicksort` should be:

`void quickSort(std::vector<int> &array, int low, int high)`

Another problem with the code is that `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` is not the correct way to get the size of a vector, the valid way is to use the `std::vector::size()` method (as also pointed out in H. Guijt's answer)

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It is wrong! With the change suggested here, the code still does not work, because the value n is calculated incorrectly in the given code.

Comment: @H.Guijt Yes, you are right. By the time I wrote this answer, the provided code did not have the version using std::vector; therefore I could not detect that problem. Your answer is indeed correct by both aspects. (I updated my answer to include that problem's solution too, but OP could change the accepted answer to yours if they wish.)

Comment: Thanks, that's not necessary. And in hindsight saying it was wrong was a bit strong; it's correct, but incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are passing the array by value, so any changes you make to it in the quicksort function will not be visible to the caller. Pass it by reference instead.
2. sizeof will return the size of the control block of the vector, not the number of bytes it is storing. Use vector::size() to get the count of elements.

Bonus: use std::swap instead of that temp variable.